# How to get complete list of followers in twitter using flex 4.6 mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, twitter, flex4, flex4.5

I am getting the list of only 20 upto 300 from the twitter api. Can any one help me How do i get complete list of followers/following at a time in flex 4.6 /action script. I successfully logined and got the acessKey.Below is my code to get the followers list.
After that twitter document said that we cannot more than 15 calls in 15 mins thats y i am getting only 300 followers list.And the document also said that application will be banned if we keep on requesting more than 15 requests in 15 mins. Please help me how to achieve this.

```
    var consumer:OAuthConsumer = new OAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            var token:OAuthToken = new OAuthToken(twitterAccessObj.accessKey, twitterAccessObj.accessSecret);
            //var postRequest:OAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest("GET",API_URL+'/1/statuses/friends.json',null,consumer, token);
            var params:Object = {};
            params.cursor = "-1";
            var postRequest:OAuthRequest = new OAuthRequest("GET",API_URL+'/1.1/friends/list.json',params,consumer, token);
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(postRequest.buildRequest(signature));
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlRequest);
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFollowerListComplete);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onTwitterIOError);
            loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onTwitterHttpStatus);
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list) says that the response is a "cursored list". This in effect means that the results are paginated for you. You get back the first 20, and then have to request the next batch. There is a link in the documentation that tells you how to use cursors to navigate their collections. I suggest reading that, and if you're still stuck, come back here and edit your question w/your latest results.

Comment: Hi Sunil, Thanks for the documentaion now i am getting next 20 set of results but here the problem is i can make only 15 requests for every 15 mins that means only 300 followers i am getting. Please help me how to get all followers list. Instead of 20 results can we get 100 so that it will be helpful.

Comment: The documentation for using cursors mentions a `count` parameter that you can use to increase the number of items returned. I'm not sure if it works, since they don't mention the `count` parameter in the docs for the "friends/list" api call.